# Sql query is running slower while using loop

Tags: sql-server, performance, loops, while-loop

> I am a newbie with sql. Please don't mind my question.

Below is the query i am currently working on. This is a simple query that fetches value from one table and insert them + other values into another Two Tables. Now the problem is that, when i ran this query for 10 seconds, Total Of 20 rows were affected. I again ran this query for 20 seconds ant 19 rows were affected. I google it and found out that while using loops in sql, the query executes slower and slower if there is more data. What can i do now to improve this query and make it faster. The loop must run for 8000+ time Please help :)

> EDIT: How can i use this query by using numbers or tally table. Can
>   anyone send the replacement of this query by using numbers or tally
>   table method?

```
DECLARE @LENGTHOFVOUCHER NVARCHAR(50), @NEXTLENGTHOFVOUCHER NVARCHAR(50), @NEXTVOUCHER NVARCHAR(50), @DEPOSITIDNOTINTRANS INT, @Y INT=1, @X INT=0, @DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT DATETIME, @MAXTRANSID INT, @DEPOSITAMOUNT DECIMAL(12, 2), @ACCOUNTNO NVARCHAR(50), @NARRATION NVARCHAR(500), @MAXROWIDOFTD INT
    SET @LENGTHOFVOUCHER=(SELECT MAX(RIGHT(VOUCHERNO,5)) FROM ACC_TRANSACTIONS WHERE VOUCHERNO LIKE 'AN%')
    WHILE @X!=8000
    BEGIN
    SET @MAXROWIDOFTD=(SELECT MAX(ROWID)+1FROM ACC_TRANSACTIONDETAILS)
    SET @NEXTLENGTHOFVOUCHER=@LENGTHOFVOUCHER+@Y
    SET @NEXTVOUCHER='AN000'+(SELECT @NEXTLENGTHOFVOUCHER)
    SET @DEPOSITIDNOTINTRANS=(SELECT DEPOSIT_ID FROM FIN_DEPOSIT WHERE DEPOSIT_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SOURCEID FROM ACC_TRANSACTIONS WHERE SOURCENAME IN ('FIN_DEPOSIT', 'FIN_INTEREST-DEPOSIT')) ORDER BY DEPOSIT_ID OFFSET @X ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
    SET @DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT=(SELECT DEPOSITDATE FROM FIN_DEPOSIT WHERE DEPOSIT_ID=@DEPOSITIDNOTINTRANS)
    SET @DEPOSITAMOUNT=(SELECT DEPOSITAMOUNT FROM FIN_DEPOSIT WHERE DEPOSIT_ID=@DEPOSITIDNOTINTRANS)
    SET @MAXTRANSID=(SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONID)+1FROM ACC_TRANSACTIONS)
    SET @ACCOUNTNO= (SELECT ACCOUNTNO FROM FIN_DEPOSIT WHERE DEPOSIT_ID=@DEPOSITIDNOTINTRANS)
    SET @NARRATION=('BEING DEPOSIT MADE | AUTOMATIC VOUCHER (DEPOSITED BY SOFTWARE PROCEDURE)')+' OF ACCOUNT NO: '+@ACCOUNTNO + ' ON: '+ ( CAST (@DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT AS NVARCHAR))
    INSERT [DBO].[ACC_TRANSACTIONS] ([TRANSACTIONID], [ORGID], [BRANCHID], [TRANSACTIONDATE], [FINANCIALYEARID], [FINANCIALPERIODID], [VOUCHERTYPEID], [REFNO], [REFDATE], [VOUCHERNO], [BANKID], [ACCOUNTNO], [CHQNO], [CHQDATE], [CHQNAME], [CURRENCYID], [EXCHANGERATE], [TOTALDR], [TOTALCR], [NARRATION], [VOUCHERSTATUSTYPEID], [RECBY], [RECDATE], [RECSTATUS], [RECVERSION], [RECAUDITLOG], [MODULE], [SOURCENAME], [SOURCEID])
    VALUES (CAST(@MAXTRANSID AS DECIMAL(18, 0)), 1, 1, CAST(@DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT AS DATETIME), CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(18, 0)), CAST(5 AS DECIMAL(18, 0)), 7, NULL, NULL, @NEXTVOUCHER, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(1.00 AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), CAST(@DEPOSITAMOUNT AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), CAST(@DEPOSITAMOUNT AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), @NARRATION , 3, N'DEBUG', CAST(@DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT AS DATETIME), N'A', 1, N'-', N'FINANCE', N'FIN_DEPOSIT', @DEPOSITIDNOTINTRANS)
    INSERT [DBO].[ACC_TRANSACTIONDETAILS]
     ([ROWID], [ORGID], [BRANCHID], [TRANSACTIONID], [TRANSACTIONDATE], [FINANCIALYEAR], [FINANCIALPERIOD], [VOUCHERNO], [LEDGERID], [DRCR], [TOTALDR], [TOTALCR], [NARRATION], [RECBY], [RECDATE], [RECSTATUS], [RECVERSION], [RECAUDITLOG])
    VALUES (@MAXROWIDOFTD, 1, 1, @MAXTRANSID, CAST(@DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT AS DATETIME), '1', '5', @NEXTVOUCHER, CAST(17 AS DECIMAL(18, 0)), N'C', CAST(0.00 AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), CAST(@DEPOSITAMOUNT AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), N'DEPOSIT MADE | AUTOMATIC VOUCHER (SOFTWARE PROCEDURE)', N'DEBUG', CAST(@DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT AS DATETIME), N'A', 1, N'-')
    INSERT [DBO].[ACC_TRANSACTIONDETAILS]
     ([ROWID], [ORGID], [BRANCHID], [TRANSACTIONID], [TRANSACTIONDATE], [FINANCIALYEAR], [FINANCIALPERIOD], [VOUCHERNO], [LEDGERID], [DRCR], [TOTALDR], [TOTALCR], [NARRATION], [RECBY], [RECDATE], [RECSTATUS], [RECVERSION], [RECAUDITLOG])
    VALUES ((@MAXROWIDOFTD+1), 1, 1, @MAXTRANSID, CAST(@DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT AS DATETIME), '1', '5', @NEXTVOUCHER, CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(18, 0)), N'D', CAST(@DEPOSITAMOUNT AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), N'DEPOSIT MADE | AUTOMATIC VOUCHER (SOFTWARE PROCEDURE)', N'DEBUG', CAST(@DATETIMEOFSTATEMENT AS DATETIME), N'A', 1, N'-')
    SET @Y=@Y+1
    SET @X=@X+1
    SET @MAXTRANSID=@MAXTRANSID+1
    SET @MAXROWIDOFTD=@MAXROWIDOFTD+1
    END
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop here at all? All you need is a numbers/tally table and this becomes 2 insert statements. The formatting of these is making my eyes bleed.

Comment: Can u explain your answer a little bit bro? I couldn't find a solution at all...

Comment: Here is an article that explains the numbers or tally table and how you can utilize it instead of a loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: This does not answer the specific question but it will solve your slowness, put this code in a transaction block so the physical writes only happen once instead of twice per loop.